# Gradle Wrapper: command not found?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

In my spring Boot web app I have added the `Gradle Wrapper` to source control so that a user does not need gradle pre-installed to run my application.

My project file Structure is shown below - note the gradle folder with `gradle-wrapper.jar` , `gradle-wrapper.properties` and `gradlew batch file` are present.

[image]

However when try to run `gradlew clean build` in this folder I get:

```
gradlew:command not found
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure this error comes from the command line? Or, asking differently, do you have a Gradle task in your `build.gradle` that tries to call gradlew again, e.g., with `exec`? What happens when you specify the full path / file name, e.g., `c:\user\you\prj\gradlew.bat clean build`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the `.` dot in your command. And from your screenshot, you're own a Windows machine so you should use the `.bat` script.

```
./gradlew.bat help
```

Comment: Running `./gradlew` or `./gradlew.bat` from the project folder which _contains_ them in root show `command not found` error. Any ideas why? Gradle home env variable is not setup, but it should not be an issue when command is executed in this way.

Comment: I am having the same problem in amazon linux